# How do I add current location into dynamic google map?

Tags: maps

I found codes for current location but I doesn't really know how to implement into the dynamic google map I have. Can anyone guide me along? Thanks.

The codes I found for current location: http://4rapiddev.com/google-api/display-user-current-location-on-google-map/

Answer (score 0):

[HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) may be this can help. look at Displaying the Result in a Map.